# What does this mean, why is the (int) in the sentence?

Tags: c

I don't know why there is `int` in parenthesis next to the `*Predicate`

```
typedef bool (*Predicate)(int);
```

Comment: `Predicate` is a function pointer; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work for what they do and how they work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typedef bool (*Predicate)(int);` means you're declaring a type named `Predicate` that is a function pointer for a function that accepts a single `int` argument, and returns `bool`. A function that meets the requirements would be:

```
bool is_zero(int val) {
    return val == 0;
}
```

and you could declare a variable like:

```
Predicate mypredicate = is_zero;
```

In this case, the likely intent is to declare a function that performs a filtering operation using a runtime supplied predicate function; it would accept `Predicate` as one of its arguments.

Answer (score 4):

This declares `Predicate` as the type of pointers to functions that take an `int` parameter and return a `bool` result. `int` is in parentheses to indicate that it is a parameter type.

You might use it like this:

```c
typedef bool (*Predicate)(int);
bool always_true(int) { return true; }
Predicate p = &always_true;
```

Comment: I believe the [generally] preferred syntax is: `Predicate p = always_true;` The `&` is unnecessary. This makes it syntax compatible with `Predicate q = p;`.

Answer (score 0):

It ia a typedef od the function pointer having one parameter of type int and returning bool

function pointers are the only place it is good to typedef pointers.

```
typedef bool (*Predicate)(int);

bool is_zero(int x)
{
   return x ==0;
}

Predicate myfuncptr = is_zero;


int main()
{
  if(myfuncptr(5)) 
    printf("Zero");
  else
    printf("Not zero");
}
```